# Get Array of Bytes from ASP.NET WEB API to be rendered in PDF using React/Redux

Tags: pdf, asp.net-web-api, react-redux

I have this action on my WEBAPI´s controller using .NET that returns bytes from SSRS report link:

```
     public IHttpActionResult GetReport(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Report"];
        var reportPath = $"{reportServer}/myReport&Id={Id}&rs:Format=PDF";
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        byte[] reportBytes = Client.DownloadData(reportPath);

        var reportBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(reportBytes);

        return Ok(reportBase64);
    }
```

When i try to generate the PDF from this return, using this react/redux code ( i am using axios)....

```
    //...code
    const reportBlob = new Blob([myReportData], { type: "application/pdf" });
    const reportBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(reportBlob);
    window.open(reportBlobUrl);
```

.....it oppened a new browser´s tab with PDF template BUT showing PDF Error as: 'FAILED TO LOAD PDF document'.

No anwsers anywhere help me resolving this problem. :(

Note:  the 'axios' call it´s returning the same array of bytes as the WEBAPI return,  so as the 'myReportData' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out by my self after 4 days. Anyone that needed this functionality (render the SSRS report in PDF within c# code returning PDF bytes from a ASP.NET WEB API,  here is the what you have to do within your webapi controller to generate the PDF bytes from report viewer namespace to be sent to your React app using Redux.

WEB API ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.6 using VS 2019):
**note**: first option i´ts commented and works the same way the option 2 that i´d prefer.

```
    // return type is Bytes
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/YourReport/{testId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetYourReportAsync(int? testId)
    {
        if (testId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            // 1. Works in this way without '?' on the end of the URL
            // URL should be like this: "http://-yourServerName-/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx"

            //ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
            //rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //rs.Url = "http://-yourServerNamein here-/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

            //// Render arguments
            //byte[] result = null;
            //string reportPath = "/-yourReportsFolderName-/-yourReportName-";
            //string format = "PDF";
            //string historyID = null;
            //string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

            //// parameters
            //ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
            //parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
            //parameters[0].Name = "yourId";
            //parameters[0].Value = testId.ToString();

            //string encoding;
            //string mimeType;
            //string extension;
            //Warning[] warnings = null;             
            //string[] streamIDs = null;
            //ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
            //ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

            //rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

            //execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

            //rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
            //string SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

            //try
            //{
            //// result type is bytes
            //    result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);                  

            //}
            //catch (SoapException)
            //{
            //    throw;
            //}  
            //// below, just in case that you want to save it locally in PDF format.            
            //try
            //{
            //    FileStream stream = File.Create(@"c:\report.pdf", result.Length);
            //    
            //    stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            //    Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.");
            //    stream.Close();
            //}
            //catch (Exception)
            //{
            //    throw;
            //}

            //return await Task.Run(() => Ok(result));

            // 2. Works this way also with '?' on the end of the URL
            // URL should be like this: "http://-yourServerName-/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx?"

            using (ReportViewer yourReportViewer = new ReportViewer())
            {
                yourReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

                // get the values from your web.config. 
                yourReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["youtReport"]);
                yourReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = $"/yourReportsFolder/yourReport";
                ;
                ReportParameter testPlanIdParameter = new ReportParameter();
                testPlanIdParameter.Name = "yourId";
                testPlanIdParameter.Values.Add(testId.ToString());

                yourReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { testIdParameter });

                byte[] yourReportBytes = yourReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");

                return await Task.Run(() => Ok(yourReportBytes));
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw ;
        }
    }
```

REACT/REDUX n**strong text**ote: you have to convert the stream of bytes returned from your WEB API Controller into BLOB format to render it in a new brownser tab in PDF format/type.

a. the  button action/behavior

```
               <div className="btn-group-vertical" role="group">

                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-success ml-2 mb-2" style={{ width: '160px' }} onClick={(e) => openReport(e, testId)}>
                            <i className="fas fa-print"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                Report
                     </button>       
                </div>
```

b. the component ( i am omiting the redux part (reducers, actions, apiservice...)

```
openReport(event, item) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.actions.loadReport(item);
    this.setState({ Report: this.props.Report });
    const ReportData = this.state.Report;

    const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
        return blob;
    }
    const ReportBlob = b64toBlob(ReportData, 'application/pdf');

    const ReportBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(ReportBlob);
    window.open(ReportBlobUrl);

}
```